# Boost post or create ads on authenticated user's post through APP Ad account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

Is it possible to boost post of 3rd party using my own app account?
Scenario-
1. user logs in and authenticate
2. user gives post id i.e `object_story_id`
3. I add campaign as as a APP owner for `object_story_id` post

here `ACCESS_TOKEN` will be of app owner of user ? will the ads be shown in users account who will pay for the ads?

```
   $access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
   $app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>';
   $app_id = '<APP_ID>';
   $id = '<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>';

   $api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
   $api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

   $fields = array(
   );
   $params = array(
   'name' => 'Sample Promoted Post',
   'object_story_id' => '<pageID>_<postID>',
    );
```

Comment: yes, the token should be of the fb user who will create/paid for ads.

Comment: Which is the real question?

Comment: @Matteo can i create ad for some other user using my ad account?

Comment: You should use the AdAccount of the user AND the fb token also

Comment: @Matteo question is can i use my account to publish ads for users authenticated with my APP?

Comment: sorry but you can't. Will the the AdAccount to pay for ads (the credit card info are owned by the adaccounts)

Comment: @Matteo yes i will pay from my credit card only as the adaccount holder